# Import a CSV to verify many users are in many groups, then export to excel file

Tags: powershell

I have been trying to write a script to verify group membership.

I have a csv file that has the following:

```
ticket, User, Group
ticket 1, User A, Group A
ticket 2, User B, Group A
ticket 3, User C, Group B
ticket 4, User D, Group A
ticket 5, User E, Group B
```

I need a script that will verify if the users are in the groups or not and have the output say if they are or not in a csv file.

Here is what I have so far that does seem to do what I want:

```
Import-CSV $File | `
ForEach {
$users = $_.User;
$group = $_.Group;
$ticket = $_.Ticket

$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$group" -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty SAMAccountName 
IF($members -contains $users) {Write-Host "$users in $group"} 
Else { Write-Host "$users not in $group"}
}
}
```

So this has the "User A is in Group A" and "User B is not in Group A" and etc. which is almost what I want.

Now how do I make my csv output file do the following:

```
Ticket, User, Group, in group?
ticket 1, User A, Group A, true
ticket 2, User B, Group A, true
ticket 3, User C, Group B, false
ticket 4, User D, Group A, false
ticket 5, User E, Group B, true
```

True = User is in the group
False = User is not in the group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the result of your test to a new NoteProperty using `Add-Member`. Ex:

```
Import-Csv -Path "c:\inputfile.csv" | ForEach-Object {

    $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.Group -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty SAMAccountName
    #in group?
    $ingroup = $members -contains $_.User
    #Add result to a new property and use -PassThru to output to pipeline
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name InGroup -Value $ingroup -PassThru

} | Export-Csv -Path "c:\outputfile.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Sample output:

```
"ticket","User","Group","InGroup"
"ticket 1","User A","Group A","False"
"ticket 2","User B","Group A","True"
"ticket 3","User C","Group B","False"
"ticket 4","User D","Group A","True"
"ticket 5","User E","Group B","False"
```

Comment: This was perfect!
I then converted it to an excel file to make it look all pretty and what not for what we are needing. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Tip: If it's the same groups over and over (or if they have a lot of members or nested groups), I would recommend storing the group-members in a hashtable so you don't retrieve the same list from AD multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$csv = @"
ticket, User, Group
ticket 1, User A, Group A
ticket 2, User B, Group A
ticket 3, User C, Group B
ticket 4, User D, Group A
ticket 5, User E, Group B
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$groups = $csv.group | select -Unique

$results = @(foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty SAMAccountName
    $csv | ? group -eq $group | select *, @{n='InGroup';e={$_.user -in $members}}
})

$results
```